# How to write fibonacci-sequence using recrusion in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, recursion, fibonacci, ternary

I have tried to create a method in Ruby which returns true if number is included fibonacci-sequence or false if it's not.

I think I got a problem when I return true or false.

Could anybody tell me why the first code doesn't work please?

```
def is_fibonacci?(num, array=[0,1])

  n = array.length - 1

  if array[n] > num
    array.include?(num) ? true : false
  end

  array << array[n] + array[n-1]
  is_fibonacci?(num, array)

end
```

When I run this code, I got this error message.

=>filename.rb:36:in `include?': Interrupt

```
def is_fibonacci?(num, array=[0,1])
  n = array.length - 1

  if array[n] > num
    if array.include?(num)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
  end

  array << array[n] + array[n-1]
  is_fibonacci?(num, array)

end
```

Second code worked.

Why can't I use

```
array.include?(num) ? true : false
```

in the code?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: def fibonacci( n )
    return  n  if n <= 1 
    fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 )
end 
puts fibonacci( 10 )
# => 55

Comment: Just a short note on conding style: `array.include?(num)` already returns `true` or `false`. You can replace the whole `if ... else ... end` block with just `return array.include?(num)`

Answer (score 2):

Shivam already gave an good answer to the question why your first version does not work.

I just want to note that there is no reason to keep all calculated fibonacci numbers in the array. That is a waste of space and probably a bit inefficient. Therefore you could simplify your method to:

```
def fibonacci?(number)
  fibos = [0, 1]
  fibos << (fibos.shift + fibos.last) while fibos.last < number
  fibos.include?(number)
end
```

Comment: creating lots of temp arrays is not super-efficient either :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: You are right. Do you like this better?

Comment: yeah, this is better, but: 1) you don't recurse (which is kinda the requirement, I think) 2) because of that you don't need the array in the signature (or even you don't need it at all). Something like this is even better: http://pastebin.com/1ew7Tktp

Comment: I like your pastebin example. I am not sure about the recursion. Because this is a really bad example for recusion, because it makes the problem bigger in each recursion instead not smaller. Therefore recursion is a bad choice to solve the problem. If the recursion is requirement because it is a homework exercise, then I don't care...

Comment: BTW, I agree that recursion should not be used here (if we're being practical). Or even loop, for that matter. There's a O(1) formula for calculating Nth fibonacci term. So we can use that and a binary search, I think.

Comment: There aren't many good examples to teach recursion. I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Some sorting algorithms like Merge or Quicksort are great examples.

Comment: But sorting is way more complicated than fibonacci :)

Comment: Maybe some tree-walking examples. Like turning AST into bytecode or whatever :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The complexity of more realistic examples is why professors start off with toy examples like Fibonacci, factorials, and integer exponentiation, and towers of Hanoi.

Comment: @pjs: I understand. But students not always understand that using recursion _here_ is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `array.include?(num) ? true : false` does not work is because you have no `return` statement. Change it to `return array.include?(num) ? true : false`. WIthout it will just call another level of the recursion algorithm and in the end run too deep into into the stack.

And just as a bonus, here is the famous one-liner using a hash:

```
fibonacci = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = k < 2 ? k : h[k-1] + h[k-2] }

p fibonacci[2]  # => 1
p fibonacci[23] # => 28657
```

Comment: Not to mention you should never use the pattern `boolean ? true : false` as the Boolean can speak for itself.

Comment: Without use of  memoization your algorithm complexity is exponential, do you really need that?

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I use `array.include?(num) ? true : false`

Syntactically there is nothing wrong in this statement and it should work fine. (it may return `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` though in context of your code as you are not returning any value).

Here is an example:

```
array = [0,1]
num = 1
array.include?(num) ? true : false
# => true
num = 3
array.include?(num) ? true : false
# => false
```

However this is horrible code. Official documentation for [`.include?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F) clearly states:

> Returns true if the given object is present in self (that is, if any
>   object == anObject), false otherwise.

Which means:

```
num = 1
array.include?(num)
# => true
num = 3
array.include?(num)
# => false
```

Again you are repeating the same mistake in the following code:

```
 if array.include?(num)
    return true
 else
    return false
 end
```

All of the above code can be replaced with just one line:

```
return array.include?(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first version, the block

```
if array[n] > num
  array.include?(num) ? true : false
end
```

is *syntactically* correct (although nasty), but *semantically* incorrect for your program because you don't return the result.  You can either add an explicit `return` on that statement, or make the rest of your program an `else` clause.  The following version works because by default Ruby returns the result on the last statement executed and only one branch of the if/else gets evaluated:

```
def is_fibonacci?(num, array=[0,1])
  n = array.length - 1
  if array[n] > num
    array.include?(num)
  else
    array << array[n] + array[n-1]
    is_fibonacci?(num, array)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the hash concept by @hirolau we can do this in two lines.

```
def fib?(n)
  @fibonacci ||= Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = k < 2 ? k : h[k-1] + h[k-2] }
  (0..n+1).any? { |x| @fibonacci[x] == n }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci numbers algorithm can be done two ways: with and w/o recursion. Recursion version must have a memoization implemented to avoid exponential complexity of algorithm.

Variant 1:

```
class Fibonacci
  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
    @array = [0,1]
  end

  def process
    return @num if [0,1].include?(@num)
    2.upto(@num).each do |i|
      @array[i] = @array[i-1] + @array[i-2]
    end
    @array[@num]
  end
end
```

Variant 2:

```
class FibonacciMemoizedRecursion
  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
    @memo = {0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 1}
  end

  def process
    recursion(@num)
  end

  private

  def recursion(a)
    return @memo[a] if @memo.include?(a)
    @memo[a] = recursion(a-1) + recursion(a-2)
  end
end
```

To test we can use MiniTest library:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class FibonacciTest < Minitest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_process_1
    assert_equal 0, Fibonacci.new(0).process
  end

  def test_process_2
    assert_equal 1, Fibonacci.new(1).process
  end

  def test_process_3
    assert_equal 1, Fibonacci.new(2).process
  end

  def test_process_4
    assert_equal 2, Fibonacci.new(3).process
  end

  def test_process_5
    assert_equal 3, Fibonacci.new(4).process
  end

  def test_process_6
    assert_equal 5, Fibonacci.new(5).process
  end

  def test_process_7
    assert_equal 8, Fibonacci.new(6).process
  end

  def test_process_8
    assert_equal 13, Fibonacci.new(7).process
  end
end
```